# Can you define alternative shorthands for Kotlin Annotations?

Tags: kotlin, annotations

I am using annotations and reflection to create a parser for some custom made files used in the project I work with

I have this annotation that will be used to annotate most data class constructor parameters

```
annotation class Element(val name: String = "",val type: ElementType = ElementType.Value)
```

the enum ElementType has these values

```
enum class XElementType {
    Value,
    Attribute,
    Ignore
}
```

is there a way to create a shorthand or alternate so that instead of using

```
@Element(type=ElementType.Ignore)
val ignoredVariable:String
```

I can use something like

```
@IgnoreElement
val ignoredVariable:String
```

which will resolve to `Element("",ElementType.Ignore)` ?

Comment: There's no native mechanism for enum aliases, if that's what you're after. But nothing prevents you from writing such an annotation and treat the presence of IgnoreElement the same way as the presence of  Element(type=ElementType.Ignore).

Comment: yeah that's the first thing I tried, I would read the annotation class and if it was IgnoreElement I tried to instantiate an Element(type=ElementType.Ignore) , the problem is that you can't instantiate annotation classes, so I figured I'd try this approach with an alias, I guess I'll have to test for many annotations for now until I find a better solution